# How to express a Python loop and a condition mathematically?

Tags: python

I have the following Python code that I want to express mathematically.

```
W = 0
for i in range(5):
    if (A > i_1) and ( (A < i_2) or (A < i_3) ):
        W = W + 1
```

This is a generic problem that I am trying to achieve; looping over some values and checking some condition. If the condition is satisfied, I want to add 1 to the counter (W in this case); otherwise, skip to the next value. How can I express this using a mathematical formula?

To be more specific:

```
for row in DF1.iterrows():
    pTime = row['A1_time']
    W = 0

    for row2 in DF1.iterrows():
        a1 = row2['A1_time']
        a2 = row2['A2_time']
        a3 = row2['A3_time']

        if (pTime > a1) and ( (pTime < a2) or (pTime < a3) ):
            W = W + 1
```

Comment: It will be either 5 or 0 depending on if your condition is met or not. Did you intend the index i to change something in your conditional statement?

Comment: The actual loop is iterating over rows in a dataframe. To simplify the question, `for i in range (5)` represents looping over some values. I will correct the code to be more clear.

Comment: Unclear the same way, how does `i_1, i_2, i_3, A` depend on `i`? And `sum(1 for i in range(5) if (A > i_1) and ( (A < i_2) or (A < i_3) ))` could be more pythonic.

Comment: I still think the answer I wrote so far applies. And also it’s pretty unpythonic to explicitly loop that way.   You would get the same thing if you did a set comprehension with the rows of the data frame filtering on your predicate, and just used ‘len’ on the result.

Comment: Loops aren’t mathematical in themselves: they’re more procedural.  If your thing is a more complicated algorithm then it might matter but right now it looks irrelevant.

Comment: I added to the code a 'simplified' example of the actual problem. I hope it makes it more clear. What I am trying to do is loop over each row in the dataframe. Each time, I will compare the values of one row to all other rows, and IF the value of the current row is less than the value of any row, I increment the counter.

Comment: @O.Mohsen So why do some of your inequalities run the other way?

Comment: @J.G. These are the conditions of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are just computing the cardinality of the set of elements meeting your conditions.

So something like $|\{x : P(x)\}|$ where $P(x)$ means $x $ satisfies your condition.

I can’t be totally sure how to elaborate until you clarify what the index has to do with the inner conditions.

---

Borrowing a bit of python syntax and using it with set notation, what I'm saying holds above for your latest example:

$|\{(x,y)\in DF1\times DF1: x.a1time > y.a1time \text{ and } x.a1time < max(y.a2time, y.a3time)\}|$

I was able to simplify the OR condition slightly by using max.  In fact, this is far closer to how I would do it with real python:

```
len([(x,y) for x in DF1.iterrows() for y in DF1.iterrows() 
     if x['a1_time'] > y['a1_time'] and x['a1_time'] < max(y['a2_time'],y['a3_time']))])
```

It can also be compressed a little bit more by using things from the `itertools` library, but this is more elementary python.

Since it looks like you don't care about the actual entries, just their count, another trick is to just create a list of $1$'s indicating each successful hit, then using `sum`. This might be a good alternative because you can do it all with generator expressions, conserving memory.

```
from itertools import product
sum(1 for x,y in product(DF1.iterrows(), DF1.iterrows())
     if x['a1_time'] > y['a1_time'] and x['a1_time'] < max(y['a2_time'],y['a3_time'])))
```

Comment: I added to the code a 'simplified' example of the actual problem. I hope it makes it more clear. What I am trying to do is loop over each row in the dataframe. Each time, I will compare the values of one row to all other rows, and IF the value of the current row is less than the value of any row, I increment the counter by 1.

Comment: @O.Mohsen Answer still doesn't change.  I added how to use what I said for the newest example.

Comment: what you mentioned here is useful **|{(x,y)∈DF1×DF1:x.a1time>y.a1time and x.a1time<max(y.a2time,y.a3time)}|**

Comment: In a similar manner, how can I include (mathematical notation) a condition where I need to increment a variable, say `L = L + someValue`, instead of a counter? This `someValue` is another attribute in the dataframe DF1.

Comment: @O.Mohsen I would just define a function $L$ such that $L(x)$ is the increment you want, and then say $\sum \{L(x):x\in X \text { and } P(x) \text{ holds}\}$ where $P$ is whatever predicate you want $x$ to satisfy.